# Cross-compiling poppler-qt4

Tags: qt4, cross-compiling, poppler

I need to know how to cross-compile libpoppler-qt4 for arm-linux.  I've downloaded the source code form http://poppler.freedesktop.org/. How to tell it to use arm-linux-gcc? and how to satisfy it's dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

To set up cross compiling you'll want the specify the host system when you run configure

eg to cross compile for arm-linux-gcc you'd use something like:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gcc
```

you may also want to specify where it gets installed to as well, since you probably don't want libraries with arm architecture on (what I assume is) a x86 machine.  To do this, specify the destination path with --prefix e.g.:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gcc --prefix=/<your destination path>
```

Bear in mind that once you specify a prefix, you're going to have to indicate this location to any other projects that depend on the library you just built, since they'll probably go looking in the default locations otherwise. (ie /usr/local/lib)

As far as dependencies goes, Poppler has several.  First up, you have Fontconfig, which itself depends on Freetype and Expat.  In order to get Poppler built in ARM architecture, you're going to have to first cross-compile each of these other dependencies, using the above configure commands.  After that, the dependencies will depend on what options you want turned on for Poppler, if you need jpeg support you'll have to get libjpeg cross compiled, if you need support for compressed PDF's you need to cross compile and link against zlib etc.

hope that helps!